# How can I find missing image in asset pipeline before deploying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am developing with Rails 3.2.8.
One annoying thing is that if an image is missing by mistake, it gives an error in production mode.

Let's say that I put the following code.

And actually I forget to place my.jpg file in app/assets/images, it's ok in development (browser will just ignore the missing image) but it gives a rails error in production mode.

How can I find the missing files before deployment?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do when building a new release for a deploy is set the following in my `config/environments/test.rb`

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest  = true
```

This mimics the `production` environment config for the asset pipeline, preventing the assets from being compiled and forcing the lookups through the `manifest.yml` files/asset pipeline. Run your tests (you do have tests, right? :-)  ) and watch for a failure.

If you don't have tests, grep you `log/development.log` for a 500 error

```
tail -f log/development.log | grep 500
```

Go through a few pages manually and watch for new log entries appearing in the tail. You should look into writing tests to automate this though.

---

The reason you're seeing the errors in production is because the asset pipeline can't find the assets you're requesting and raises exceptions due to this. In development things are more lenient so that debug info can be presented to you in favor of the 500 errors. By changing the above config in your environment, you're telling rails to act strictly with respect to it's response to missing assets through the asset pipeline, allowing you to catch the problem before it makes it's way to production.

Answer (score -1):

You can watch the rails console running in dev mode... it shows a warning when it can't find the image.

Also, use the browser's error console. Both of those will tell you what's missing and then you just start grepping or visually searching to see where you did (or didn't) put the image.

I don't know why it would be annoying that the production server is less kind to the broken code than when you were in development unless you actually want to roll out code with missing objects and references.

Comment: This isn't the best idea, as there are circumstances where an image may appear fine in development based on how it's linked/referenced in a stylesheet/in the DOM, but may not be fed through the asset pipeline (or worse, during a deploy the author forgets to recompile the assets with `rake assets:precompile`). In such a scenario your checks against the rails or browser consoles will fail (no errors/warnings will occur in development), but the 500 errors will still come in production because the asset is missing in the pipeline.

Comment: A thank you for whoever gave me the spanking. I haven't been overriding the asset pipeline and the consoles have worked pretty well for me so far... I didn't consider the cases where code used wouldn't use the pipeline.